# What is an affine space called without the vector space structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

An affine space can be defined as a set $A$ together with a vector space $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$ such that a vector defines a map from the set to itself.

$$\overset{\rightarrow}{A} \times A \rightarrow A$$

(along with some conditions on that map)

What is it called if you lose the ability to multiply by scalars for $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$, so it is no longer a vector space but instead just a group?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand, but perhaps you're looking for a [$G$-torsor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsor)?

Comment: . . . . . .sheaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you said it sounds simply a [group action on a space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action), a free and/or transitive action, if you keep those conditions.

I wasn't aware of the terminology $G$-torsor, but it looks accurate too.

Comment: That's not simply a group action because it goes "along with some conditions on that map". Those conditions are precisely that the map is a free and transitive action, which in this case define a $G$-torsor.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira I suppose you could say that, so I revised. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira I had no way of knowing what conditions were being referred to, really. There are some conditions on the map just for a group action too.

Comment: Sure, a group action could work here and your answer was precise at the beginning. The thing is that an affine space is really just a space $A$ with a free and transitive action of $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$, so a more natural "one-step relaxation" of it would discard the scalar product and keep everything else. Besides, it's a good chance to talk about $G$-torsors, which are important. See http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira appreciated the Baez article, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An 'affine space over $\Bbb Z$'. This would be exactly your definition except that $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module rather than a vector space over whatever field. The point is that allowing scalar multiplication by elements of $\Bbb Z$ adds no extra structure because $n\times v$ can already be defined using just the additive structure: $n\times v = \underbrace{v + \dots + v}_{n\text{ times}}$.