# Definition and terminology concerning one-dimensional vector spaces without further structure

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, mathematical-physics

One-dimensional vector spaces without a norm or any "further structure" are of course sets (in the following e.g. set $\mathcal V$) with some rather basic suitable properties; surely involving suitable "algebraic structure" consisting of multiplication with real numbers and comparison (equality, or inequality) of resulting products. Is the following definition of a (any "real") one-dimensional vector space correct and complete ? :

- Its non-null elements are all "commensurate (with respect to real numbers)" to each other:

$$\forall \, \mathbf a \in \mathcal V : (1 * \mathbf a \ne 0 * \mathbf a) \implies (\forall \, \mathbf b \in \mathcal V : \exists \, s_{ba} \in \mathbb R \, | \,  1 * \mathbf b = s_{ba} * \mathbf a),$$

- and its elements are each unique (with respect to the above "commensurability"):

$$\forall \, \mathbf a, \mathbf b \in \mathcal V : (1 * \mathbf a = 1 * \mathbf b) \implies (\mathbf a \equiv \mathbf b).$$

**My question:**
Are such basic properties and algebraic structure described and discussed more abstractly in the mathematics literature, perhaps using different terminology ?

Also, might those basic one-dimensional vector spaces without "further structure" perhaps be commonly known by some simpler, shorther name -- such as "commensurate spaces" ?

Note: I am interested in the described properties of one-dimensional vector spaces without a norm or any "further structure" as mathematical representation of the so-called "*[commensurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) of values of the same physical quantity*" (and "*incommensurability of values of distinct physical quantities*"); i.e. not necessarily in so-called ["*mathematical commensurability*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics)).

Comment: A one dimensional vector space over a field $F$ is basically just $F$ itself.

Comment: You seem to restrict attention to vector spaces over the field of real numbers.  I don't know any reason you should not call these (one-dimensional) real vector spaces.  Closely related but with slightly less structure are (one-dimensional) real affine spaces.

Comment: @Berci: "_A one dimensional vector space over a field $F$ is basically just $F$ itself._" -- In a sufficiently loose sense of "_basically_", sure. But I'm looking to include one-dimensional vector spaces without multiplication being defined for pairs of its elements (i.e. **more basic** than any [field $F$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)); and therefore especially without any "multiplicative identity" (or "norm").

Comment: @hardmath: "_You seem to restrict attention to vector spaces over the field of real numbers._" -- That's matched to the examples of values of physical quantities I'm considering, as [eigenvalues of self-adjoint (measurement-)operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Properties_of_bounded_self-adjoint_operators). "_I don't know any reason you should not call these (one-dimensional) real vector spaces._" -- Fair enough, thanks, but: Do we know whether this terminology is the only terminology being used by everybody?

Comment: @Berci: I'm looking for a more precise and technical expression of the phrase "_basically the field itself_" you used in your above comment; perhaps such as "the equivalence class of all (similar) fields, under arbitrary scaling".

Comment: You might call it a torsor.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: "_You might call it a torsor._" -- Thanks, interesting. (In preparation of my question I had come accross the first comment under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664038/what-is-an-affine-space-called-without-the-vector-space-structure) ... Would you please consider expanding your comment into an answer, thereby also possibly naming the specific kind of torsor applicable to my question?